# Send(Beam) WiFi Configuration via NFC to another NFC capable device(Android)

Tags: android, wifi, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am creating a Android App that does a bunch of stuff. One of the capability of the App is to be able to transfer "Current Wifi Configuration" to another device. Is there any predefined format(something like a MIME type) to store Wifi config.

Also, is it possible to write the Wifi Configuration in to a NFC tag. Is there a predefined record structure for this. Later is it possible to scan the tag and load the Wifi Config in to another device ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the right permissions you can fetch the configuration (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html): you'd probably need to compress it somehow before you serialize it and then write it into an NFC tag. On the other device you'd read it, decompress/deserialize and then create a new WifiConfiguration to add to the other device. [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) has the methods you need to create/update the configuration.